# Xamarin.Android Linking problem - Error processing method System.String

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin-linker

I have a Xamarin Android app that compiles and runs fine in DEBUG mode but won't compile in RELEASE mode.

The error that I'm getting is:

```
Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.String Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SQLite.Interop.NativeMethods::sqlite3_errmsg(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SQLite.Interop.SafeSqliteHandle)' in assembly: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.String SQLitePCL.raw::sqlite3_errmsg(SQLitePCL.sqlite3)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()   MedLemnMobile.Android   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets    366
```

I've tried "Skip Linking" for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll

I've tried "Skip Linking" for SQLitePCLRaw.core

Neither of the above tries at "Skip Linking" fixed the problem.
The app compiles fine if I set Linking to "None", but that is not recommended for RELEASE mode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

2/22/2021 - I turned up the verbosity on the Build Output and did a search for System.String. Here's what I found:

```
Activator call 'System.Object System.Reflection.Assembly::CreateInstance(System.String)' inside 'System.ValueTuple`2<System.Int32,System.Reflection.MethodInfo> CompilerClassLibNETStandard.Compiler::CompileInMemory(System.String)' is not yet supported (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo System.Type::GetField(System.String,System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' inside 'Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement::Xamarin.Forms.StyleSheets.IStylable.GetProperty(System.String,System.Boolean)' was detected with argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Void MedLemnMobile.ViewModels.GraphViewModel::MethodBeginModeReduce(System.String)' was detected with type name `MedLemnMobile.Classes.` which can't be resolved. (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'System.Object System.Activator::CreateInstance(System.Type)' inside 'System.Void MedLemnMobile.ViewModels.GraphViewModel::MethodBeginModeReduce(System.String)' was detected with 1st argument expression which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Expression call 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,System.Reflection.MethodInfo)' inside 'System.Void MedLemnMobile.ValidRules.ValidatableObject`1::set_IsValid(System.Boolean)' was detected with 2nd argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Expression call 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,System.Reflection.MethodInfo)' inside 'System.Void MedLemnMobile.ValidRules.ValidatableObject`1::a(System.Collections.Generic.List`1<System.String>)' was detected with 2nd argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Expression call 'System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Property(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,System.Reflection.MethodInfo)' inside 'System.Void MedLemnMobile.ValidRules.ValidatableObject`1::set_Value(T)' was detected with 2nd argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'System.Object System.Activator::CreateInstance(System.Type,System.Object[])' inside 'System.Void MedLemnMobile.Classes.Utils/a::MoveNext()' was detected with 1st argument expression which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Object Xamarin.Forms.BindablePropertyConverter::ConvertFromInvariantString(System.String)' was detected with type name `Xamarin.Forms.` which can't be resolved. (TaskId:466)
5>  Expression call 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression System.Linq.Expressions.Expression::Call(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,System.Reflection.MethodInfo,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)' inside 'System.Void MedLemnMobile.Behaviors.EventToCommandBehavior::a(System.Reflection.EventInfo,System.Object,System.Action`2<System.Object,System.EventArgs>)' was detected with 1st argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Type Java.Interop.__TypeRegistrations::Lookup(System.String[],System.String)' was detected with argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions::GetRuntimeMethod(System.Type,System.String,System.Type[])' inside 'System.String Humanizer.EnumHumanizeExtensions::GetCustomDescription(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' does not use detectable instance type extraction (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions::GetRuntimeMethod(System.Type,System.String,System.Type[])' inside 'System.String Humanizer.EnumHumanizeExtensions::GetCustomDescription(System.Reflection.MemberInfo)' does not use detectable instance type extraction (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo System.Type::GetField(System.String,System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' inside 'System.Void Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Shared.Lightup.NullableSyntaxAnnotationEx::.cctor()' does not use detectable instance type extraction (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Reflection.FieldInfo System.Type::GetField(System.String,System.Reflection.BindingFlags)' inside 'System.Void Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Shared.Lightup.NullableSyntaxAnnotationEx::.cctor()' does not use detectable instance type extraction (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String,System.Boolean)' inside 'System.Type Roslyn.Utilities.ReflectionUtilities::TryGetType(System.String)' was detected with argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Boolean Roslyn.Utilities.UICultureUtilities::TryGetCurrentUICultureSetter(System.Action`1<System.Globalization.CultureInfo>&)' was detected with type name `System.Globalization.CultureInfo, System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a` which can't be resolved. (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Type Roslyn.Utilities.ObjectReader::ReadType()' was detected with argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'System.Object System.Activator::CreateInstance(System.Type)' inside 'System.Object Microsoft.DiaSymReader.SymUnmanagedFactory::CreateObject(System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.Boolean,System.String&,System.Exception&)' was detected with 1st argument expression which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'T System.Activator::CreateInstance()' inside 'T Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DecodeWellKnownAttributeArguments`3::GetOrCreateData()' is not supported (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'T System.Activator::CreateInstance()' inside 'T Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EarlyDecodeWellKnownAttributeArguments`4::GetOrCreateData()' is not supported (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'T System.Activator::CreateInstance()' inside 'System.Void Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalysisState/BlockAnalyzerStateData`2::.ctor()' is not supported (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'System.Object System.Activator::CreateInstance(System.Type)' inside 'System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableArray`1<TExtension> Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.AnalyzerFileReference/Extensions`1::GetAnalyzersForTypeNames(System.Reflection.Assembly,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<System.String>,System.Boolean&)' was detected with 1st argument expression which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String)' inside 'System.Type Roslyn.Utilities.ObjectReader::ReadType()' was detected with argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Reflection call 'System.Type System.Type::GetType(System.String,System.Boolean)' inside 'System.Type Roslyn.Utilities.ReflectionUtilities::TryGetType(System.String)' was detected with argument which cannot be analyzed (TaskId:466)
5>  Activator call 'T System.Activator::CreateInstance()' inside 'System.Void Roslyn.Utilities.IDictionaryExtensions::MultiAdd(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<TKey,TCollection>,TKey,TValue)' is not supported (TaskId:466)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000: Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.String Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SQLite.Interop.NativeMethods::sqlite3_errmsg(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SQLite.Interop.SafeSqliteHandle)' in assembly: 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.String SQLitePCL.raw::sqlite3_errmsg(SQLitePCL.sqlite3)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
5>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets(366,5): error XALNK7000:    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute()
5>Done executing task "LinkAssemblies" -- FAILED. (TaskId:466)
5>Done building target "_LinkAssembliesShrink" in project "MedLemnMobile.Android.csproj" -- FAILED.: (TargetId:492)
```

Comment: Hi, how about setting **Link SDK Assemblies** to check whether it works?

Comment: Link SDK Assemblies Only is the setting that I'm using when it fails to compile.

Comment: Okey, from shared error, do you also add `SQLitePCL.sqlite3` to the skip linking?

Comment: I edited the issue (above) and included a portion of the Build Output, with the verbosity turned up, where the string "System.String" shows up.

Comment: Hi, do you have added the `SQLitePCL.sqlite3` to the skip linking? You could see the last line of updated log also shows the `SQLitePCL.sqlite3`.

Comment: Yes - I have tried skip linking for SQLitePCL.sqlite3 with no luck.

Comment: I have now tried Skip Linking for each of the assemblies mentioned in the error message:
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SQLite.Interop.NativeMethods

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SQLite.Interop.SafeSqliteHandle

Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces

SQLitePCL.raw

SQLitePCL.sqlite3

None of these attempts has fixed my linking problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SUCCESS! I got it to work as follows:

1.) I discovered that setting Linking to "Sdk and User Assemblies" got the app to build OK, but then, when it ran, the user interface didn't behave well.

2.) So then, I added to my "Skip Linking" list, the name of my main Xamarin.Forms shared-code project.

And, thank goodness, that got it to build and run cleanly!

Answer (score 0):

I tried clearing bin and obj, did many things and no help. In the end I turned off the "Multi-Dex" in my Android Property for it to compile. Below are my settings.

[image]